Why llm_chain.invoke(ques_VN) output is interrupted when it is being printed?
I have a problem related to using llm_chain.invoke() to return the answer from ChatGPT. More specificially, when I want the function to return the answer, the output cannot be completed and is interrupted. I still don't understand what happens to llm_chain.invoke().
I've use the max_tokens=4600 to the function but it didn’t make sense. The document of llchain also didn't have any idea about this error. You can check the image for more details.
The error when using output parser in llmchain
question = f'''You are a data analyst.
I have a list of results after training a csv data file as follows
{results_str}
Please help me evaluate these results and comment on the performance of the trained models.
Please briefly explain it.
'''

final_report = llm_chain.invoke(question)
print("final_report: ", final_report)
st.write(final_report)`

I have passed max_tokens=4600 to the function but it did not make sense. The document of llchain also didn't have any idea about this error. You can check the image for more details.
I really hope that the output parser of LangChain can return the completely full answers instead of the interrupted answers

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Oh I've update the image but I don't know why the post didnt have it
You can check it via this link: https://imgur.com/a/Ayqt3g2
I still dont understand why I've encountered it
